# Filtering correct frequency from data

Tags: python, data-science, frequency

I'm trying to filter out a signal from some data using a butterworth function. The signal is fairly clean but I can't seem to filter it out correctly.

I've tried using different ranges of frequencies with no luck (the frequency is between 1Hz and 1.3Hz). I've also tried using different orders but haven't really been able to find a good

```
data = [351.1475409836066,351.1475409836066,351.1475409836066,350.93877551020404,350.93877551020404,350.93877551020404,350.93877551020404,351.1475409836066,351.1475409836066,351.18367346938777,351.1475409836066,351.1475409836066,351.1475409836066,351.1475409836066,351.5702479338843,351.1475409836066,351.1475409836066,351.1475409836066,350.69387755102036,350.2834008097166,350.2834008097166,350.2834008097166,350.2834008097166,350.3225806451613,350.3225806451613,350.3225806451613,350.3225806451613,350.3225806451613,350.08064516129036,350.08064516129036,350.08064516129036,350.08064516129036,350.4878048780488,350.5263157894737,350.5263157894737,350.5263157894737,350.5263157894737,350.93877551020404,350.93877551020404,350.93877551020404,351.1475409836066,351.1475409836066,351.18367346938777,351.18367346938777,351.1475409836066,351.1475409836066,350.93877551020404,350.93877551020404,350.93877551020404,350.93877551020404,350.93877551020404,350.93877551020404,350.93877551020404,351.1475409836066,351.1475409836066,351.1475409836066,351.1475409836066,351.1475409836066,351.1475409836066,351.1475409836066,351.1475409836066,351.5702479338843,351.6049382716049,351.6049382716049,351.6049382716049,351.8181818181818,352.06611570247935,352.3140495867769,352.06611570247935,352.06611570247935,352.75,352.5,352.75,352.5,352.0331950207469,352.06611570247935,352.06611570247935,352.06611570247935,352.06611570247935,352.06611570247935,352.09876543209873,352.09876543209873,352.3140495867769,352.0331950207469,352.28215767634856,352.06611570247935,352.06611570247935,352.06611570247935,352.06611570247935,352.3140495867769,352.3140495867769,352.3140495867769,352.3140495867769,352.3140495867769,352.3140495867769,352.75,352.75,352.75,352.75,353.2217573221758,353.2217573221758,353.2217573221758,353.0,352.5311203319502,352.3140495867769,352.3140495867769,352.34567901234567,352.34567901234567,352.34567901234567,352.5619834710744,352.3140495867769,352.3140495867769,352.5619834710744,352.3140495867769,352.3140495867769,352.5619834710744,352.3140495867769,352.5619834710744,352.3140495867769,352.75,352.75,352.75,352.97071129707115,353.0,353.0,353.2217573221758,353.2217573221758,353.67088607594934,353.67088607594934,353.9240506329114,353.9240506329114,354.1525423728814,354.1525423728814,354.1525423728814,353.9240506329114,353.25,353.02904564315355,353.02904564315355,353.02904564315355,353.02904564315355,353.02904564315355,353.25,353.25,353.4728033472803,353.4728033472803,353.25,353.25,353.4728033472803,353.4728033472803,353.9240506329114,353.9240506329114,354.1525423728814,353.8983050847458,354.1276595744681,354.1276595744681,354.61538461538464,354.84978540772534,354.59227467811155,355.0862068965517,355.0862068965517,355.0862068965517,355.0862068965517,354.84978540772534,354.1525423728814,353.4728033472803,353.02904564315355,353.02904564315355,353.02904564315355,353.02904564315355,352.7800829875519,353.0,353.0,353.0,352.7800829875519,352.7800829875519,352.7800829875519,352.7800829875519,352.7800829875519,352.7800829875519,352.7800829875519,352.7800829875519,353.0,353.0,353.0,353.0,353.2217573221758,353.2217573221758,353.2217573221758,353.2217573221758,353.2217573221758,352.75,352.09876543209873,352.34567901234567,352.34567901234567,351.91836734693874,351.6734693877551,352.09876543209873,351.85185185185185,351.85185185185185,351.85185185185185,351.85185185185185,351.85185185185185,351.85185185185185,351.85185185185185,351.85185185185185,351.85185185185185,352.06611570247935,352.09876543209873,352.09876543209873,352.09876543209873,352.5311203319502,352.5311203319502,352.5311203319502,352.75,353.0,352.7800829875519,352.7800829875519,352.09876543209873,351.6734693877551,351.6734693877551,351.4634146341463,351.42857142857144,351.42857142857144,351.42857142857144,351.42857142857144,351.42857142857144,351.42857142857144,351.42857142857144,351.42857142857144,351.42857142857144,351.42857142857144,351.42857142857144,351.85185185185185,351.85185185185185,351.85185185185185,351.85185185185185,351.85185185185185,351.85185185185185,351.85185185185185,352.06611570247935,352.06611570247935,352.09876543209873,352.09876543209873,352.09876543209873,352.06611570247935,351.85185185185185,351.42857142857144,351.2195121951219,351.2195121951219,351.2195121951219,351.42857142857144,351.42857142857144,351.42857142857144,351.42857142857144,351.42857142857144,351.42857142857144,351.42857142857144,351.42857142857144,351.2195121951219,351.42857142857144,351.42857142857144,351.42857142857144,351.85185185185185,351.85185185185185,351.85185185185185,352.06611570247935,352.06611570247935,352.06611570247935,352.06611570247935,352.06611570247935,352.09876543209873,352.5311203319502,352.5311203319502,352.5311203319502,352.5,351.85185185185185,351.85185185185185,351.42857142857144,351.6734693877551,351.6734693877551,351.42857142857144,351.85185185185185,351.85185185185185,351.85185185185185,351.85185185185185,351.85185185185185,351.85185185185185,351.85185185185185,351.85185185185185,351.85185185185185,351.85185185185185,351.85185185185185,352.06611570247935,352.06611570247935,352.09876543209873,352.09876543209873,352.5311203319502,352.5311203319502,352.5311203319502,352.5311203319502,352.5311203319502,352.7800829875519,353.0,353.25,352.75,352.5619834710744,352.34567901234567,351.91836734693874]





from scipy.signal import butter, lfilter
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import freqz

def butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    low = lowcut / nyq
    high = highcut / nyq
    b, a = butter(order, [low, high], btype='band')
    return b, a


def butter_bandpass_filter(data, lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
    b, a = butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=order)
    y = lfilter(b, a, data)
    return y


def run():


    # Sample rate and desired cutoff frequencies (in Hz).
    fs = 30.0
    lowcut = .9
    highcut = 1.5

    # Plot the frequency response for a few different orders.
    plt.figure(1)
    plt.clf()
    for order in [3,4,5]:
        b, a = butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=order)
        w, h = freqz(b, a, worN=2000)
        plt.plot((fs * 0.5 / np.pi) * w, abs(h), label="order = %d" % order)

    plt.plot([0, 0.5 * fs], [np.sqrt(0.5), np.sqrt(0.5)],
             '--', label='sqrt(0.5)')
    plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
    plt.ylabel('Gain')
    plt.xlim((0,2)) 
    plt.legend(loc='best')

    # Filter a noisy signal.
    T = 10.266666666666667
    nsamples = T * fs
    t = np.linspace(0, T, nsamples, endpoint=False)
    a = 0.02
    f0 = .8

    plt.figure(2)
    plt.clf()
    plt.plot(t, data, label='Noisy signal')


    y = butter_bandpass_filter(data, lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5)
    plt.plot(t, y, label='Filtered signal (%g Hz)' % f0)
    plt.xlabel('time (seconds)')
    plt.hlines([-a, a], 0, T, linestyles='--')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.axis('tight')
    plt.legend(loc='lower left')
    plt.ylim((-40,40))   # set the ylim to bottom, top
    plt.show()


run()
```

The peaks of the filtered data clearly doesn't match up with the peaks of the data and i'm not sure why. It seems to me that the original data is fairly clean (you can visually see the peaks if you plot it).

This may be a separate question but I know that the frequency of my peaks are not regular and are variable (probably within .2Hz) but because it's such a big percentage of the actual Hz I'm afraid that's a problem. Could the variability in the frequency be causing this problem?

Thanks!

[image: filtered data]

[image: raw data]

So my sampling rate was 30Hz for the raw data, hence why the x-axis scale is multiplied by 30.

Comment: Could you add plots to your question? Unfiltered, actual filterered, and expected filtered?

Comment: @bphi I've add the images in now!